# Magento: 500 internal server error :: Back-end >> System >> Tools >> Backups

Tags: magento

We are unable to create magento backups from “ Back-end >> System >> Tools >> Backups” menu on magento version 1.5. When we are trying to create a backup after 15 to 20 mints system return a error message:

---

> ```
> Internal Server Error 
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable
> to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator, webmaster@choosemadeinusa.com and     
> inform them of the time the error
> occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the
> error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error
> log.
> ```

Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

> Apache/2.2.23 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.23 OpenSSL/0.9.8e-fips-rhel5
>   mod_auth_passthrough/2.1 mod_bwlimited/1.4 FrontPage/5.0.2.2635 Server
>   at www.choosemadeinusa.com Port 443

---

We have applied almost every solution which we found on magento forum, since a lot of people faced that issue previously. The solutions which we have applied are:

- Change permissions to 777 on “var” folder.
- Made “var/backups” folder empty.
- Changed permissions of ROOT index.php file to 755.
- Increased the MAX TIME of execution in PHP.
- Increased the Memory limit.
- Replaced index.php file with the index.php.sample for temporary bases.
- Enabled the “Log Settings” to see what error system is generating. Check the attached “system.log” to see any error related to maganto backups?
- Replaced “split” with “explode” php function in the file “app/code/local/MageWorx/LinkExchange/Controller/Router.php”

But, no luck found we are really unclear what is wrong. We are planning to upgrade the magento version from 1.5 to 1.7 and we cannot start that process b/c we are unable to complete the backup process.

The worst part is when system returns the error message “500 internal server error” , then we reload the Dashboard page of back-end and it shows us message in green color that your “backup process has been completed”, it also shows the list of backups which system has created. But, we are sure that is not a complete backup OR should we assume that the backup has been completed?

```
2013-02-07T16:54:15+00:00 ERR (3): Deprecated functionality: Function split() is deprecated  in /home/choosema/public_html/app/code/local/MageWorx/LinkExchange/Controller/Router.php on line 56
2013-02-07T16:54:15+00:00 ERR (3): Strict Notice: Declaration of MageWorx_SeoSuite_Block_Catalog_Navigation::_renderCategoryMenuItemHtml() should be compatible with that of Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation::_renderCategoryMenuItemHtml()  in /home/choosema/public_html/app/code/local/MageWorx/SeoSuite/Block/Catalog/Navigation.php on line 38
2013-02-07T16:54:25+00:00 ERR (3): Strict Notice: Declaration of MageWorx_SeoSuite_Block_Catalog_Navigation::_renderCategoryMenuItemHtml() should be compatible with that of Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation::_renderCategoryMenuItemHtml()  in /home/choosema/public_html/app/code/local/MageWorx/SeoSuite/Block/Catalog/Navigation.php on line 38
2013-02-07T16:54:29+00:00 ERR (3): Strict Notice: Declaration of MageWorx_SeoSuite_Block_Catalog_Navigation::_renderCategoryMenuItemHtml() should be compatible with that of Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation::_renderCategoryMenuItemHtml()  in /home/choosema/public_html/app/code/local/MageWorx/SeoSuite/Block/Catalog/Navigation.php on line 38
2013-02-07T16:55:08+00:00 ERR (3): Strict Notice: Declaration of MageWorx_SeoSuite_Block_Catalog_Navigation::_renderCategoryMenuItemHtml() should be compatible with that of Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation::_renderCategoryMenuItemHtml()  in /home/choosema/public_html/app/code/local/MageWorx/SeoSuite/Block/Catalog/Navigation.php on line 38
2013-02-07T16:55:17+00:00 ERR (3): Strict Notice: Declaration of MageWorx_SeoSuite_Block_Catalog_Navigation::_renderCategoryMenuItemHtml() should be compatible with that of Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation::_renderCategoryMenuItemHtml()  in /home/choosema/public_html/app/code/local/MageWorx/SeoSuite/Block/Catalog/Navigation.php on line 38
```

The above errors we got from “system.log” file there are errors on “Router.php” and “Navigation.php” is that something wrong with URL rewriting? As per our understanding “500 internal server error” also returns if routing is not correct.

Can anybody let us know and help us out what is going wrong since we have tried almost everything. Also, please check the attached “system.log” file may be someone can find a clue what is wrong with backup system of magento.

Comment: It looks like you're still getting a timeout.  It's possible that the backup is completing, especially since you're getting the confirmation message when you refresh.  Do you have access to your web server's error logs?  That will tell you exactly what's happening when the site hits the 500 error.  You should have a corresponding entry in that log file for the date/time that you receive the error.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, measuring the exact time would be very helpful at determining where the problem is, getting it it within a min could lead to an exact timeout.

Could be `wait_timeout` in MySQL's configuration /etc/my.cnf

Secondly, there is nothing magical about the backup process.  It sounds like you have a working knowledge and access to your server.  You can use `zip` to zip up the whole magento web root, and use `mysqldump` to get a copy of database.  That is all that you really need to rebuild a PHP/MySQL application.

Also, it almost sounds like you are planning on trying to upgrade Magento 1.5->1.7 on a live production server.  This is almost certainly a mistake, numerous features will change and extensions may or may not play nicely with the new version.  I highly suggest doing the backup as described above, and deploying to some sort of a testing environment where you can do the upgrade and take notes on what problems occur.

Comment: The added advantage of a tar 'n mysqldump is that the process is a lot faster than the resource heavy gui php glup. Don't fear the reaper, the command line is your friend.

Comment: Agreed, but depending on how big your DB is and the workload of your server, mysqldump might need to be run on off peak hours due to it locking the tables when it runs.

Comment: The backup is not completing we have verified that previously:

mySQL DB Size: 1026.40 MB
Website Files Size: 2.8GB

The backup generated 2 .zip files of 72.2 MB for mySQL DB and the actual size of the mySQL DB is 1026.40 MB so clearly this is not a complete back-up of the system. The back-up system is breaking and not completing.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Yes, you are right we've full access of the server and we know how to take the backup of the mySQL DB and website files/folders using the SSH. Since, we are unable to take the complete backup of the website from the back-end, then we have the final option to take the backup from the SSH.

Comment: "72.2 MB for mySQL DB and the actual size of the mySQL DB is 1026.40 MB so clearly this is not a complete back-up of the system"  Not necessarily.  MySQL statements are practically an ideal data type for compression.  Try doing `mysqldump -u {user} -p {dbname} | gzip > {dbname}.sql.gz` and compare file size.

Answer (score 1):

To find out what the error is, you can uncomment the line

## ini_set('display_errors', 1);

The line is located in the index.php file.

Then you will see what exactly triggers the above mentioned error.

Answer (score 0):

In magento 1.9.1 when you get the 500 internal server error, simply change permission of the index.php to 644, delete any maintenance-flag.php in your root folder too. You should then be able to log into admin panel!

Answer (score 0):

using godaddy server,
change the "index.php" file permission on 644 in your root folder.

Comment: Could you please work on proper grammar and punctuation? This answer may be helpful, but it would use some style edition. Did you mean "I solved this type of problem"? Also, you mention godaddy server, that wasn't mentioned before - could you elaborate?